# how to advance sscanf C?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I'm given a char* arguments. Which is basically a input stream that consists of "hex-address new_val" and I need to read both values as int*. I'm using sscanf() and reading hex-address just fine, but I can't figure out the way to advance to read new_val.No matter what I tried - I get segfault. Here is what I have so far:

```
 int set_new_val(Cmd *cp, char *arguments) {

  int* addr;

  int* val;

  sscanf(arguments, "%x",&addr);

  sscanf(arguments+?????, "%x",&val);

  /*see if I read it correct*/

  printf("adr = %x || val = %x\n",(unsigned int)*addr,(unsigned int)*val);

  /*not finished*/

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read them at once? You can read more than one variable in `sscanf`. Just add it in the format string and in the arguments.

Comment: to mszymborski: I didn't you could do that. Thanks.

Comment: you could also take the string 'arguments' and use strtok() to format each value as a sub string then use sscanf() on each returned value/pointer from strtok()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int addr, val; // not int*

sscanf(arguments, "%x %x",&addr, &val);

printf("adr = %x || val = %x\n", addr, val);

Comment: with more experience, the 'over complicate things' syndrome tends to go away, especially if you write the code,  then come back to it a few days later to review what you have done.